# JAVA bouncing ball is freezing

Tags: java, swing

I have created bouncing ball app in Java. Everything is working as supposed but ball is freezing when it's moving. When I move the cursor to the window the ball is moving smoothly. When I stop moving the cursor it's again freezing.

OS: Fedora 23
JDK: 8

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
}
}

class Game extends JFrame {

public Game(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Ball ball1 = new Ball();
    add(ball1);
    setSize(400,300);
    setTitle("Bubbles");
    setVisible(true);
}

}

class Ball extends JPanel implements Runnable{
int radius = 50;
int x = 5 ;
int y = 5;
int dx = 2;
int dy = 2;

public Ball (){
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x,y,radius,radius);
}

public void moveBall (){

    if (x + dx > 400 - radius){
        x = 400 - radius;
        dx = -dx;
    } if (x + dx < 0){
        x = 0;
        dx = -dx;
    }
    else {
        x += dx;
    }

    if (y + dy > this.getHeight() - radius){
        y = this.getHeight() - radius;
        dy = -dy;
    } if (y + dy < 0){
        y = 0;
        dy = -dy;
    }
    else {
        y += dy;
    }

}


@Override
public void run() {
    while (true){
        moveBall();
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: it works for me too :/

Comment: I tested the code and nothing freezes. (OS: WIN10 JDK: 8) so it must be a Fedora thing.

Comment: What installation are you using for Fedora? I don't remember Java supporting it.

Comment: @user1803551 if you asking jdk installation it's jdk1.8.0_71-b15

Comment: No, I'm asking for [which OS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) it is.

Comment: Fedora 23 Workstation (gnome 3.18)

Comment: Is it in [this list](http://java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml)?

Comment: @user1803551 not in the list, can it's be problem for it ?

Comment: I guess. If you install any software on an OS which isn't in the supported list I assume there could be problems. Don't know the specifics. That's why I asked which installation you chose in the first link I gave.

Comment: i suspected it's can be OS problem, thank you for reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works, but using Thread in Swing like this is not the best way [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

In your case a swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) would be more appropriate.

**Example**

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(17, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ball1.runMe();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

The `runMe` method will be similar to your current `run` method just remove the `while` and `Thread.sleep`.

```
public void runMe() {
    moveBall();
    repaint();  
}
```

Naturally your `Ball` will not implement the `Runnable` anymore so you remove all Threading code

Comment: Thank you @peter this is very useful article, i must read this.

Comment: @DadashMemmedli Your welcome, me to where using improperly thread's in swing environment, and this creates unexpected behavior.